# Not translate error messages from attributes

Tags: attributes, format, translation, abp

I have an encapsulation of the attribute of maximum length, where we specify the format that it has to have, but in the message that is returned it is not translated.

However, in the field itself it does display the translation

If I make the call from the API, the message returned is as follows